# How to handle errors for AIRFLOW (DatabricksSubmitRunOperator)

Tags: airflow, azure-databricks

I have Airflow dag , which runs series of Databricks notebook.

Now What i want is , if any one the notebook got failed? How to send mail to user that this notebook got failed with few details like execution date.

and is there any error handling way?

Comment: Add your DAG code

Answer (score 0):

The `BaseOperator` has parameters which allow to configure sending emails in case of failure thus it's available to all operators:

```
DatabricksSubmitRunOperator(...,email_on_failure=True,
                            email='your.email@where.com')
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step1:** Set `email_on_failure` to `False` and use the operators’s `on_failure_callback`. `on_failure_callback` the function described below.

```
from airflow.utils.email import send_email

def notify_email(contextDict, **kwargs):
    """Send custom email alerts."""

    # email title.
    title = "Airflow alert: {task_name} Failed".format(**contextDict)

    # email contents
    body = """
    Hi Everyone, <br>
    <br>
    There's been an error in the {task_name} job.<br>
    <br>
    Forever yours,<br>
    Airflow bot <br>
    """.format(**contextDict)

    send_email('you_email@address.com', title, body)
```

**Step2:** Short example airflow dag below

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators import PythonOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

args = {
  'owner': 'me',
  'description': 'my_example',
  'start_date': days_ago(1)
}

# run every day at 12:05 UTC
dag = DAG(dag_id='example_dag', default_args=args, schedule_interval='0 5 * * *')

def print_hello():
  return 'hello!'

py_task = PythonOperator(task_id='example',
                         python_callable=print_hello,
                         on_failure_callback=notify_email,
                         dag=dag)

py_task
```

Note where set `on_failure_callback` equal to `notify_email` in the `PythonOperator`.