# How to include my LOGS of my airflow task in the email triggered on failure

Tags: airflow, azure-databricks

I have a Dag with DataBricks Run Operator Task. Now on failure of this Dag, it notifies the user that this task is failed. Now i want to include the execution of Databricks Notebook URL into the Mail , it will be available if we go to the logs manually.

Can anyone help me how to get that property with link of execution of Databricks Notebook

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle errors for AIRFLOW (DatabricksSubmitRunOperator)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68063583/how-to-handle-errors-for-airflow-databrickssubmitrunoperator)

Comment: No it didnt , I want to add the execution link of Databricks notebook in the email.